# Multiple csv files to one csv file - Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

I have been reading through some of the previous posts about the concept, but all the solutions i find very different from eachother.

I have multiple csv's devided over seperate folders (all with kind of the same path but the subfolders are different).

I now need to import these csv's, change the headers and export it into one single csv.

I have been trying with this but im getting a very weird error: Import-Csv : Cannot open file "C:\Windows\system32\Book1.csv"
Although my path is refering to C:\csv ?

```
$CSVFolder = 'C:\csv\';                                                               #'
$OutputFile = 'C:\export\test3.csv';

$CSV= @();

Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVFolder -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    $CSV += @(Import-Csv -Path $_)
}

$CSV | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Force;
```

I was thinking of using a datatable for the headers, but its not so clear to me at this point. Also the issue with the error is not clear for me...

Comment: Use `$_.FullName` I guess.

Comment: `@(Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName)` that is

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted:

- **`Import-Csv -Path $_` should be `Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName` in your code**,

  - (Strictly speaking, it should be `Import-Csv -LiteralPath $_.FullName`, because strings passed to the `-Path` parameter are subject to wildcard resolution).
- because the **`[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances representing files returned by `Get-ChildItem` are converted to *strings* when they are passed to the `-Path` (or `-LiteralPath`) parameter as a *command-line argument*** (as opposed to via the pipeline), in which case the **the *mere file name* rather than the *full path* is used**, if your `Get-ChildItem` command targets a *directory* in *Windows PowerShell* (see background information below).

  - A mere filename such as `Book1.csv` is interpreted as relative to the *current* directory (which happened to be `C:\Windows\system32` in your case), so `Import-Csv` looks for file `C:\Windows\system32\Book1.csv` rather than the intended `C:\csv\Book1.csv`.
  - Note that *piping* `Get-ChildItem` output to cmdlets is generally *not* affected by this, because the `.PSPath` property (which PowerShell adds behind the scenes) containing the full path (including PS provider prefix) binds to the `-LiteralPath` parameter.
    Note that as of PSv5.1.14393.693, however, this mechanism is *broken* for `Import-Csv`, due to a bug.

---

This is **a common pitfall that occurs whenever `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances are passed to cmdlets that accept file paths via `[string]`(-array)-typed parameters *as arguments*.**

To be safe: **Always use `.FullName` when you pass objects received from `Get-ChildItem` to another command *as a parameter value*** (as opposed to via the pipeline) to ensure that the full path is passed.

---

#### Optional background information:

This behavior is a *pitfall*, because it is perfectly reasonable to assume that passing a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance *as-is* to a command that accepts file paths works, given the object-oriented nature of PowerShell - especially, since it *does* work reliably when using the *pipeline* rather than a parameter value.

Unfortunately, the built-in cmdlets that accept file paths (`-Path`, `-LiteralPath` parameters) do so as `[string]`s only (there is no parameter set that accepts `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances directly), and it is in the course of `[System.IO.FileInfo]`-to-string conversion that the problem arises.

**There also wouldn't be a problem if the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances *consistently* evaluated to the files' *full paths*, which is unfortunately not the case in *Windows PowerShell* (this has since been fixed in PowerShell *Core*):**

- `Get-ChildItem <directory>` outputs `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances that evaluate to *file names only* in a string context.
- `Get-ChildItem <literalFilePathOrWildCardExpr>` outputs `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances that evaluate to *full paths*.

In other words: It is only if `Get-ChildItem` targets a *directory* (folder) that the objects it returns evaluate to their file *names* only in a string context.
Targeting a specific file or using a wildcard expression results in full paths, by contrast; with `Get-Item`, that's always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to 'fullname' property, instead of 'name'.

Ex:

```
PS /Users/adil/Downloads> gi *csv |select name                                                                  

Name              
----              
tradesdownload.csv


PS /Users/adil/Downloads> gi *csv |select name, fullname                                                                

Name               FullName                                
----               --------                                
tradesdownload.csv /Users/adil/Downloads/tradesdownload.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code. This code take all csv file, import them and take only column 1, 2, 3 and change column name to header1, header2, header3, then export all into new csv file

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp2" -Filter "*.csv" | 
    %{Import-Csv $_.FullName -Header header1, header3,header4} | 
                    Export-Csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation


#a short version (for no purist)
gci "C:\temp2" -Filter "*.csv" | %{ipcsv $_.FullName -Header header1, header3,header4} | epcsv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoType
```